# 100% width on navigation in a column overflows the page in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to strech my navigation to 100% of the column.
If I use width:100% the navigation streches all over the page.

Do I have to set the width manually for every screen size?
This is for a school and we are forced to use bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
        <ul id="navigation" class="nav nav-stacked affix">
            <li><a href="#">Fixed navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-sm-10">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#right {
background-color: lightblue;
}

#left {  /* For showing the column width */
background-color: orange;
height: 100vh;
}

#navigation{
background-color: lightgreen;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Here is better look at it.
https://www.bootply.com/TKjfHrza8M

Comment: because you have `.affix` on your navigation which sets its position to `fixed` and takes it out of the flow of the document. So its new context is the document not the `col-sm-2` like you think it is. So it's taking 100% width of its new context... the whole document.

Comment: @zgood - Ohh I see, removing it actually did fill it the right way. Does this mean I can't have it fixed then? Thats something I really need here.

Comment: You can have it fixed, you would just probably have to write `@media` query styles to change its width to match the `col-sm-2` when it changes size

Comment: @zgood - Great, seem to work great this way!

Answer (score 0):

Try using fit-content for height and width. Add padding, if needed.

```
#navigation{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: cool property value but [bad support](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content) :(